# mirth administrator won't load on certain user accounts

Tags: mirth

I have a mirth system on a windows server. The system was running properly. Then, suddenly, I was only able to launch Mirth Administrator when logged in as Admin on Windows Server. For all other accounts, if I right click the mirth icon in the system tray, click Run Administrator and give my credentials, Mirth will hang on "Loading Preferences." If I am not logged in as administrator then all of the buttons are greyed out in the Mirth Server Manager menu and if I click OK, I get an error message saying "could not save file conf\mirth.properties"

It seems like Mirth is suddenly having trouble communicating with the mirthdb--maybe because of a permissions issue. But I can't figure out why.

The only change I've made to the system is installing .NET 4.

Any suggestions on how to debug this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why your users would have had access in the first place, but in my experience, for all applicable non-administrative accounts, AD security groups, etc, you need to grant read/write permissions to C:\Program Files\Mirth. Also, if you have configured the Mirth Service to run under a particular non-administrative account, then that account will also need permissions to the Mirth folder.

However, there is an alternative means of accessing the Mirth Administrator. Instead of logging directly into the server, open a web browser on your local machine, and navigate to:

```
http://myservername:8080
```

You should be greeted with a webpage, and on it, a single buttom labelled "Launch Mirth Connect Administrator." So long as you have the JVM installed on your local machine, you should be able to load and launch the Mirth Administrator directly from there.